# Quarkus Hibernate ORM in OpenShift: Import.sql not executed

Tags: hibernate, openshift, quarkus

I have a Quarkus app that I deploy in OpenShift. application.properties includes the following config:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create

quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default
quarkus.smallrye-graphql.ui.always-include=true
```

This configuration results in schema being effectively created. However the database is not populated. All tables are empty. It seems import.sql is ignored.

To avoid this, I tried following:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:import.sql'
```

This results in the import.sql indeed being executed. However this execution is happening before the schema is generated, causing a tome of errors that say that tables do not exist.

How do I resolve this? Outside of OpenShift the first configuration above works as expected.

Comment: Are you using a native image or are you running in JVM mode?

Comment: It's Quarkus on JVM. No native compilation. The command to deploy is: quarkus build -Dquarkus.kubernetes.deploy=true -Dquarkus.profile=dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *prod* mode, the `import.sql` is not read (on purpose).
If you still want to load the data, you need to add:

```
%prod.quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=import.sql
```

By default, this property is set to `no-file`.

Note that you can use a different file name in `prod` if you need.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. I thought appending -Dquarkus.profile=dev to the build command would force deployment in dev mode. It seems I was wrong.